Question regarding Second Isomorphism Theorem proof in a book
In the page 150 of “Algebras, Lattices and Varieties”, this proposition is enunciated :
“ Let $f: A \to B$ and $g : A \to C$ be homomorphism such that ker($f$) $\subseteq$ ker($g$) and $f$ is onto $B$. Show that there is a unique homomorphism $h : B \to C$ satisfying $g(x) = h(f(x))$ ”
The proof begins defining the relation $h =$ {($g(x),f(x)$) : $ x \in A$}. Then the authors claim that this relation is a function from $B$ to $C$ and that it’s an homomorphism.
Now, my question is : Why is that function $h$ a function from $B$ to $C$? In particular, why from $B$ to $C$? The authors state this, but I don’t see it. Because $g(x)$ is in $C$, and $f(x)$ is in B, how can I say that $h$ is from $B$ to $C$?
Thanks.

First, perhaps it would be better to consider the relation $h = \{(f(x),g(x)) : x \in A\}$, since you're right that the domain of the original version would come from $C$ not $B$.
Now to prove this is a function requires two properties, existence and uniqueness.
Existence: For any $y \in B$ there is an $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$ (because onto) so $(f(x),g(x)) \in h$.
Uniqueness: Suppose $(f(x),g(x)), (f(y),g(y)) \in h$ where $f(x)=f(y)$. Then we want to show $g(x)=g(y)$. But $f(x)f(y)^{-1} = f(xy^{-1}) = 1$ so $xy^{-1} \in \ker(f) \subseteq \ker(g)$ so $1 = g(xy^{-1}) = g(x)g(y)^{-1}$ so $g(x)=g(y)$.
